# Why is this chi-squared test negative?

Tags: r, chi-squared-test

[image]

I ran two models, one  restricted and another unrestricted.The log-likelihood value of the unrestricted model is however unexpectedly smaller than the restricted one. Could anyone tell me what the problem is?

Comment: Please edit your question as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: As started by NelsonGon, it helps to have a reproducible question. This includes sample code (including listing non-base R packages), sample data (e.g., `dput(head(x))`), and expected output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info. Further, please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/).